# Comparing two imbalanced signal transmission

Tags: data-acquisition

Below shows a perfectly balanced system assuming cables are balanced and twisted:
[image]
Im wondering if the transmitter is not impedance balanced, would a balanced receiver reject CM interference still much better than single ended receiver:

For example below the total imbalance seems 100 Ohm:
[image]

But if one uses the receiver as single ended the total impedance seems like 101kOhm.
[image]

Would that make a huge difference also in terms of common mode interference rejection? And is there a way to quantify it?

Are there transducers which are not differential signalling but impedance balanced?

Comment: As drawn, the yellow resistors provide no termination in either case. They are shorted by the signal source.

Comment: Your first circuit doesn't represent what I would call a balanced signal transmission system. It then follows that the rest of your circuits would be flawed as they seek to modify the original circuit. This means your question doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the maths you will find that the impact depends on the ratio of the imbalance to the RX common mode impedance, 100R:100k for example will give a common mode to differential mode conversion of -60dB, 100R:10k will be -40dB, 100R:1k will be -20dB and so on, it is just a potential divider.

It is for this reason that one figure of merit for a differential receiver is a very high common mode impedance, and why things like the THAT Corp bootstrapped line receivers are such a brilliant idea.

There are plenty of microphones that are impedance balanced, and they work perfectly well.